# Network shows http response undefined Angular 13

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to get the products from **NestJS** server.And the products are coming but the attached images are not visible.According to some stackoverflow answers we have to convert the coming images into their format.But the thing is I'm receiving an entire object list not just images.So I tried to seprate the images from `subscribed` data using `map` function.And after implementing some conversion function logic, I'm getting `undefined` in **Network Panel**

In the following screen shot you can see the `undefined with text/html type` response in Network tab,and below the network tab details,all the image paths are visible in **console panel**

[image]

**get method in service.ts file.By setting `responseType:'blob' gives error,so I didn't set blob`**

```
public getallbooks(): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpclient.get(
      `${this.API_SERVER}/books`
      //  {
      //   responseType: 'blob',
      // }
    );
  }
```

**component.ts file here is the function for converting images and also displaying the product**

```
  image!: any;
  results?: Book[];

ngOnInit() {
    this.apiService.getallbooks().subscribe((data: Book[]) => {
      this.results = data;
      const arr = this.results?.map((i) => {
        return i.coverimage;
      });
      this.createImageFromBlob(arr);
      console.log(this.results);
      console.log(arr);
});
 }
createImageFromBlob(image: any) {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    (reader.onload = () => {
      this.image = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(
        reader.result as string
      );
    }),
      false;
    if (image) {
      reader.readAsDataURL(new Blob([this.image]));
    }
  }
```

**html code**

```
<div class="grid" *ngFor="let result of results">
      <div class="blog-card spring-fever" style="padding: 0.5rem; z-index: 100">
        <img
          class="image"
          [src]="'http://localhost:3000/' + image | safeurl"
          alt=""
          height="400px"
          width="250px"
          style="border: 1px solid red"
        />
```

Comment: It is not the response. It's your request URL. Probably something you pass the URL is undefined.

Comment: So what would be the solution?

Comment: Well, the usual suspect is `[src]="'http://localhost:3000/' + image | safeurl"` . Image is loaded asynchronously it might be undefined when the `img` element is rendered you may want to wrap the `img` in  `*ngIf` or use an `async` pipe

Comment: @Eldar I tried with `*ngIf='image'` and network shows `Name:Security Status 200 Type text/html`.

Comment: @Eldar And I don't know how to use `async` pipe here.When I use pipe like this `[src]="'http://localhost:3000/' + image | async"` ,it gives me error about `Observabales and promises and no overload matches`

Comment: Ok, it seems you are trying to create a URL from a Blob and assign it to an `img` element. In this case, I think the final assignment should be:`[src]="image | safeurl"`

Comment: @Eldar I'm getting `SafeValue%20must%20use%20[property]=binding:%20data:application/octet-stream;base64,dW5kZWZpbmVk%20(see%20https://g.co/ng/security#xss):1          GET http://localhost:4200/SafeValue%20must%20use%20[property]=binding:%20data:application/octet-stream;base64,dW5kZWZpbmVk%20(see%20https://g.co/ng/security 404 (Not Found)` with `[src]="image | safeurl"`

Comment: It seems you don't need to use `safeurl` pipe.

Comment: @Eldar with `[src]="image"`  network shows `Request URL: data:application/octet-stream;base64,dW5kZWZpbmVk
` status 200.  `type octet-stream` And images are not visible

Comment: Ok, so far so good. Now you need to fix `reader.readAsDataURL(new Blob([image]));`

Comment: @Eldar I have added some code at the end of my question it might help you to understand the things

Comment: @Eldar I also suspect  `(new Blob([this.image]))` fishy here.

Comment: You need to remove `this` there.

Comment: @Eldar with this `(new Blob([image]))`, result is same.Like this `(new Blob(image))`, result also same

Comment: @Eldar Have my `file upload ` code  provided some help?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247183/discussion-between-eldar-and-m-nouman).

Comment: @Eldar ok meet me there

Answer (score 1):

**So in my case** I had a  list of books and each book has path for its image. I was using `ngFor` and set the image `src` with the path. That is the right way. But the images were not visible and Network was showing images as `text/html` type. The actual issue here was not the `type`,the actual issue was in my `URL`.I had a folder in NestJs server by the name of `assets`,that is present at `root`, and I had set the path for the images(in NestJs file upload code), like this `./assets/`. That is also the correct way to set the destination folder.I was able to see the images at browser like this `http://localhost:3000/imagename.png`,and that means my server configured to server/serve my images over root URL that's why I  can access them `http://localhost:3000/imagename.png`. But my api was returning images in a format that contains `./assets/` in the URL. So with the following code

```
<div *ngIf="image">
          <img
            class="image"
            [src]="'http://localhost:3000/' + image | safeurl"
            alt=""
            height="400px"
            width="250px"
            style="border: 1px solid red"
          />
        </div>
```

I am assuming that I'm hitting the Url like this  `http:localhost:3000/imagename.png` with `pipe safurl` to sanitize and tell Angular that this url is safe. But actually Angular was seeing the URL like this `http:localhost:3000/./assets/imagename.png`. And **this is note the correct URL Format**. Urls don't work with `.` or `,`.Also becasue my server is configured at root, this url`http;//localhost:3000/assets/imagename.png` is also wrong.And `root` means that, whatever the thing is set at `root`, that is directly access able after your server's port number. Example `http://localhost:YourServerPortNumber/TheThing_Set_at_Root`.

> **So the solution for this issue is the following**

```
src="http://localhost:3000/{{
              result.coverimage.replace('./assets/', '')
            }}"
```

> And also this

```
<div *ngIf="result.coverimage">
          <img
            class="image"
            src="http://localhost:3000/{{
              result.coverimage.replace('./assets/', '')
            }}"
            alt=""
            height="400px"
            width="250px"
            style="border: 1px solid red"
          />
        </div>
```

With above `.replace('./assets/', '')` we are removing the `./assets/` and repalcing it with `''` empty space. So now URL is in this format`http://localhost:3000/imagename.png`.

Also I can remove `safeurl pipe` for now beacuse it is `localhost`,but in prodction mod I will be needing that pipe. And It might happen that even with localhost somebody might need the pipe.

**Also now I don't need the `createImageFromBlob()` function and the `map` or other array methode to extract all the images from subscribed data,and simply you can write your code like this to display the data**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.apiService.getallbooks().subscribe((data: Book[]) => {
      this.results = data;
      console.log(this.results);
  });
  }
```

**I hope I understood the things myself correctly and explained them correctly**